# Using .constantize to invoke both a class and method from separate strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to call a class and method which are both stored as strings in the DB.
I would be looking to create an object from these 2 strings:

```
class_name = 'Some::Class'
method_name = 'a_method'
params = {foo: 'bar'}

class_name.new(params).method_name
```

I have used `constantize` before for a similar approach, but I'm not sure exactly what the best solution is here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `const_get`:

```
Class.const_get(class_name).new(params).public_send(method_name)
```

Comment: Usually `Object.const_get` is used to get top-level constants.

Answer (score 3):

`class_name.constantize.new(params).send(method_name)` should work?

If you want to send args with the method, you can use, for example, `.send(method_name, params)`

If you're getting the data from external sources, I'm not sure how secure `constantize` is, but it works smoothly and is nicely readable. You can also use `classify` if the format of the class name could vary.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails`, therefore I suggest using [`safe_constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-safe_constantize) (available in Rails only) and [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send) (plain Ruby):

```
class_name = 'Some::Class'
method_name = 'a_method'
params = {foo: 'bar'}

class_name.safe_constantize.new(params).public_send(method_name)
```

Comment: What is the reason? `NameError`(constantize) vs `NoMethodError`(safe_constantize)? IMO, `NameError` is clearer.

Answer (score -1):

If the use of [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) is safe you could do the following.

```
module Some
  class Klass
    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end
    def a_method
      puts "keys = #{@params.keys}"
    end
  end
end

class_name = 'Some::Klass'
params = { foo: 'bar', oof: 'rab' }
method_name = 'a_method'

str = "%s.new(%s).%s" % [class_name, params, method_name]
  #=> "Some::Klass.new({:foo=>\"bar\", :oof=>\"rab\"}).a_method"
eval str
keys = [:foo, :oof]
```

This approach obviously has wide application.